# Producer-consumer using semaphore in C

Tags: c, linux, multithreading, pthreads, producer-consumer

There is producer-consumer problem is written using semaphore. In below code, there is an issue of synchronization execution while the consumer is created. And for its solution, sleep statement is added in switch block of the consumer.
 Kindly help me with the efficient solution for the synchronization. Any suggestion for the improvement of code is really helpful.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<pthread.h>
#include<unistd.h>
#include<semaphore.h> /* sem_t */
#include<stdlib.h>

#define BUF_SIZE 2

struct buffer {
        int data;
};

struct buffer buf[BUF_SIZE];

sem_t fill, empty;

int value, i;

void *producer(void *data);
void *consumer(void *data);

int main(void)
{
    int sel, prod_data, cons_data;
    int k;

    if (sem_init(&empty, 0, BUF_SIZE)) {
        printf("Error: semaphore not initialize\n");
        return -1;
    }
    if (sem_init(&fill, 0, 0)) {
        printf("Error: semaphore not initialize\n");
        return -1;
    }

    while (1) {
        printf(".........................................................\n");
        printf("Selection\n");
        printf("Producer : 1 | Consumer : 2 | Display : 3 | Exit : 0 || ");
        scanf("%d",&sel);
        printf(".........................................................\n");

        switch (sel) {
        case 1:
            sem_getvalue(&empty, &value);
//          printf("Prod_e: %d\n", value);
            sem_getvalue(&fill, &value);
//          printf("Prod_f: %d\n", value);
            printf("\nProducer\n");
            pthread_t prod_t;
            printf("Enter data:");
            scanf("%d", &prod_data);
            if (pthread_create(&prod_t, NULL, producer, (void *) &prod_data)) {
                printf("Error: thread not created\n");
                return -1;
            }
            break;
        case 2:
            printf("\nConsumer\n");
            sem_getvalue(&empty, &value);
//          printf("Cons_e: %d\n", value);
            sem_getvalue(&fill, &value);
//          printf("Cons_f: %d\n", value);
            pthread_t con_t;
            if (pthread_create(&con_t, NULL, consumer, (void *) &cons_data)) {
                printf("Error: thread not created\n");
                return -1;
            }
            if (i == 0) {
                printf("Buffer empty\n");
                break;
            }
//              sleep(1); // if commented then synchronization issue
            printf("Consume data: %d\n", cons_data);
            break;
        case 3:
                if (i == 0) {
                    printf("Buffer empty\n");
                    break;
                }
                for (k = 0; k < i; k++)
                    printf("buf[%d]: %d\n", k, buf[k].data);
                break;
        case 0:
            sem_destroy(&fill);
            sem_destroy(&empty);
            exit (0);
            break;
        }
    }
    sem_destroy(&fill);
    sem_destroy(&empty);
    return 0;
}

void *producer(void *arg)
{
    int data = *(int *) arg;

    if (sem_wait(&empty)) { /* wait */
        printf("Error: sem wait fail\n");
        pthread_exit(NULL);
    }

    buf[i].data = data;
    i++;

    if (sem_post(&fill)) { /* post */
        printf("Error: sem wait fail\n");
        pthread_exit(NULL);
    }

    pthread_exit(NULL);
}

void *consumer(void *arg)
{

    if (sem_wait(&fill)) { /* wait */
        printf("Error: sem wait fail\n");
        pthread_exit(NULL);
    }

    i--;
    *(int *) arg = buf[i].data;

    if (sem_post(&empty)) { /* post */
        printf("Error: sem wait fail\n");
        pthread_exit(NULL);
    }
    pthread_exit(NULL);
}
```

Output without sleep statement:

```
Selection
Producer : 1 | Consumer : 2 | Display : 3 | Exit : 0 || 1

Producer
Enter data: 11

Selection
Producer : 1 | Consumer : 2 | Display : 3 | Exit : 0 || 3

Display
buf[0] = 11

Selection
Producer : 1 | Consumer : 2 | Display : 3 | Exit : 0 || 2

Consumer
Consume data: 4196464
```

If sleep statement is added in consumer block then expected output(in our case 11) is obtain. 
Due to sleep statement insertion, consumer thread get enough time to complete its execution compared to case 2 statements of switch and provide expected output.

Comment: can you please be more specific with the problem?

Comment: Yeah - how can there be a synchro problem?  You create the PC queue, then the producer/consumers.

Comment: Also note: for a bounded PC queue that is safe for multiple producers/consumers, you need two semaphores and a mutex, (or three semaphores), or the equivalent condvars.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that your main thread runs to the point where it displays the data that the consumer thread is supposed to "return". But there's no synchronization between the main tread and the consumer.

the easiest solution (that still uses threads) is to have the main thread join the consumer thread - that's how it can know the consumer has completed its work.  Instead of a call to sleep, try:

```
pthread_join(con_t, NULL);
```

You actually have a similar synchronization problem with the `producer()` thread, it's just that it's not apparent because you don't do anything with the data that the produce thread updates until after getting more input. So the race condition has plenty of time to complete in a way that produces the results you expect.

However, keep in mind that your program isn't actually taking advantage of concurrency - it creates threads, but doesn't perform any significant work in parallel.  You might as well make direct calls to `producer()` and `consumer()`.