# Need help in implementing the Producer-Consumer problem with pthread and semaphore

Tags: c++, operating-system, pthreads, semaphore

I am trying to implement the Producer and Consumer problem in C++ using pthread and semaphore. I have one Producer and two consumers. My producer reads a string from a file and stores it in a queue character by character. The consumers read from the string and store in a char character also one by one. The problem is that only one of my Consumer is reading from the queue, other is not and its array is remaining empty. How do I fix this problem. Here is my program:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<pthread.h>
#include<fstream>
#include<unistd.h>
#include<semaphore.h>
#include<queue>

// define queue size
#define QUEUE_SIZE 5

// declare and initialize semaphore and read/write counter
static sem_t mutex,mutex1;
//static int counter = 0;

// Queue for saving characters
static std::queue<char> charQueue;

// indicator for end of file
static bool endOfFile = false;

// save arrays
static char consumerArray1[100];
static char consumerArray2[100];


void *Producer(void *ptr)
{
    int i=0;
    std::ifstream input("string.txt");
    char temp;
    while(input>>temp)
    {
        sem_wait(&mutex);
        charQueue.push(temp);
        sem_post(&mutex1);
        sem_post(&mutex);
        //counter++;
        std::cout<<"Procuder Index: "<<i<<std::endl;
        i++;

        sleep(6);
    }
    endOfFile = true;
    pthread_exit(NULL);
}

void *Consumer1(void *ptr)
{
    std::cout<<"Entered consumer 1:"<<std::endl;
    int i = 0;
    sem_wait(&mutex1);
    //while(charQueue.empty());
    sem_post(&mutex1);
    while(!endOfFile)// || !charQueue.empty())
    {
        sem_wait(&mutex1);


        sem_wait(&mutex);

        std::cout<<"Consumer1 index:"<<i<<" char: "<<charQueue.front()<<std::endl;
        consumerArray1[i] = charQueue.front();
        charQueue.pop();
        //std::cout<<charQueue.size()<<std::endl;

        sem_post(&mutex1);
        i++;
        //counter--;

        sem_post(&mutex);
        sleep(2);
    }
    consumerArray1[i] = '\0';
    pthread_exit(NULL);
}

void *Consumer2(void *ptr)
{
    std::cout<<"Entered consumer 2:"<<std::endl;
    int i = 0;
    sem_wait(&mutex1);
    //while(charQueue.empty());
    sem_post(&mutex1);

    while(!endOfFile)//  || charQueue.empty())
    {
        sem_wait(&mutex1);


        sem_wait(&mutex);

        std::cout<<"Consumer2 index: "<<i<<" char: "<<charQueue.front()<<std::endl;
        consumerArray2[i] = charQueue.front();
        charQueue.pop();
        sem_post(&mutex1);
        i++;
        //counter--;

        sem_post(&mutex);
        sleep(4);
    }
    consumerArray2[i] = '\0';
    pthread_exit(NULL);
}

int main()
{
    pthread_t thread[3];
    sem_init(&mutex,0,1);
    sem_init(&mutex1,0,1);
    pthread_create(&thread[0],NULL,Producer,NULL);
    int rc = pthread_create(&thread[1],NULL,Consumer1,NULL);
    if(rc)
    {
        std::cout<<"Thread not created"<<std::endl;
    }
    pthread_create(&thread[2],NULL,Consumer2,NULL);
    pthread_join(thread[0],NULL);pthread_join(thread[1],NULL);pthread_join(thread[2],NULL);
    std::cout<<"First array: "<<consumerArray1<<std::endl;
    std::cout<<"Second array: "<<consumerArray2<<std::endl;
    sem_destroy(&mutex);
    sem_destroy(&mutex1);
    pthread_exit(NULL);
}
```

Edit: I added semaphore around the access of `charQueue.empty()` and `charQueue.push()` as well, but no change in output. what else should I do?

Comment: The producer and the first consumer are pretty much synchronized because they both `sleep` the same amount. If you make them sleep different amounts, or make all three threads sleep a random amount of time, things would probably be different.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude I specifically want the first consumer to read 2 char and then the 2nd to read every 3rd char. any suggestions on implementing that?

Comment: Instead of sleeping (which is quite unpredictable anyway), how about using condition variables to signal between the two consumers? The first consumer fetches two characters, then signals the second consumer, which then consumes its single character and then signal the first consumer.

Comment: FYI, `while(charQueue.empty())` in `Consumer2` is missing a semi-colon like the one in `Consumer1`. Not that it will matter much. that sort of busy waiting and the sleep artifacts are a terrible idea. a cond var, a counter, and a queue, would be ideal for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have the same problem that you had before. Your `Consumer1` function can call `charQueue.empty` while your `Producer` function can be calling `charQueue.push(temp);`. You may not access an object in one thread while another thread is, or might be, modifying it. You either need to protect `charQueue` with a mutex, with a semaphore, or with some other form of synchronization primitive.

Again, the compiler is free to optimize code like this:

```
while(charQueue.empty());
```

To code like this:

```
if (charQueue.empty()) while (1);
```

Why? Because your code may be accessing `charQueue` at any time. And it is expressly prohibited for one thread to modify an object while another thread may be accessing it. Therefore, the compiler is permitted to assume that `charQueue` will not be modified while this loop is executing and so there is no need to check it for emptiness more than once.

You have sempahores. Use them to ensure that only one thread might touch `charQueue` at a time.

Comment: but I have used semaphores. I have put a wait before the push and post after. same for pop and empty ?

Comment: See my update. Your `while(charQueue.empty());` loop is obviously wrong. Where's the sempahore that's supposed to be controlling access to the queue?

Comment: so how can I check if queue is empty or not. Also I did use semaphore.

Comment: You can check if the queue is empty or not in code that uses a semaphore to ensure that no other thread could modify the queue while it is checking if the queue is empty. (It may help to search around for code that uses a semaphore and a queue to see how to use the semaphore to do this. Maybe start by looking at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50023380/producer-consumer-using-semaphore-in-c) question.)

Comment: should I use the same semaphore or create different semaphore for that?

Comment: You may need one semaphore to ensure that only one thread can touch the queue at a time and a separate semaphore to allow threads to wait for the queue to be non-empty.

Comment: but the `charQueue.empty()` is being accessed as while loop condition. how to I use semaphore threre?

Comment: @ShantanuShinde Instead of spinning on the queue, you block on a semaphore and arrange to have any thread that makes the queue non-empty also unblock the semaphore.

Comment: please read my edited code and tell what else should I be doing. also I tried printing size of queue. it gives some garbage large number. and the loop is not stopping on queue becoming empty

Comment: I'm kind of puzzled by your code now. You have `mutex` and `mutex1`. I presume that one is to wait for the queue to be non-empty and one protects the queue from concurrent access? Is that right? If so, which is which?

Comment: mutex1 is for queue, mutex for other

Comment: So then why does the producer call `sem_wait(&mutex)`? The producer doesn't want to wait for the queue to be non-empty. In fact, the producer calls `sem_wait` on both of them -- but it definitely doesn't ever want to wait for the queue to be non-empty.

Comment: I think I misunderstood the problem. is the problem that both consumers accessing empty at the same time?

Comment: **Producer**: Get right to access queue. Put object on queue. Release right to access queue. Signal that queue is not empty. **Consumer**: Wait for queue to be non-empty. Get right to access queue. Get object from queue. Mark that queue might be empty. Release right to access queue.

Comment: so I must use like this. **Producer**: `sem_wait(&mutex);....sem_post(&mutex);sem_post(&mutex1);` **Consumer**:`sem_wait(&mutex1);...sem_wait(&mutex);....sem_post(&mutex);sem_post(&mutex1);`

Comment: That looks closer to what you want. ;)

Comment: and one more thing, the access for empty must be in between `sem_wait(&mutex1) `and `sem_wait(&mutex)` in **Consumer**

Comment: did that. no change. same output. check the edited code

Comment: Your consumer still calls `charQueue.empty` without holding the semaphore that protects it (in the `while` statement).

Comment: in the while loop? but if I don't do that and if producer finishes reading file, the execution wont go inside the loop

Comment: I removed every `charQueue.empty()` from the code. I am still getting the same output. also the `charQueue.size()` returns some weird large value. what is happening?

Comment: I made some code that is working. I will put it as an answer, please suggest improvement on it, please.

Answer (score 0):

Using guidelines from @DavidSchwartz I made this code that is working. Please suggest me a better way to implement it, as in if there are better and safer ways to do the things I have done. Sorry for me not getting most of the comments and answer as this is my first code using pthreads and semaphore. So, please bear with me:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<pthread.h>
#include<fstream>
#include<unistd.h>
#include<semaphore.h>
#include<queue>

// define queue size
#define QUEUE_SIZE 5

// declare and initialize semaphore and read/write counter
static sem_t mutex,mutex1;
//static int counter = 0;

// Queue for saving characters
static std::queue<char> charQueue;

// indicator for end of file
static bool endOfFile = false;

// save arrays
static char consumerArray1[100];
static char consumerArray2[100];


void *Producer(void *ptr)
{
    int i=0;
    std::ifstream input("string.txt");
    char temp;
    while(input>>temp)
    {
        sem_wait(&mutex);
        charQueue.push(temp);
        sem_post(&mutex1);
        sem_post(&mutex);

        i++;

        sleep(6);
    }

    endOfFile = true;
    sem_post(&mutex1);
    pthread_exit(NULL);
}

void *Consumer1(void *ptr)
{

    int i = 0;
    sem_wait(&mutex1);
    bool loopCond = endOfFile;
    while(!loopCond)
    {

        if(endOfFile)
        {

            loopCond = charQueue.empty();
            std::cout<<loopCond<<std::endl;
            sem_post(&mutex1);
        }
       sem_wait(&mutex1);


        sem_wait(&mutex);


        if(!charQueue.empty())
        {

            consumerArray1[i] = charQueue.front();
            charQueue.pop();
            i++;
        }        
        if(charQueue.empty()&&endOfFile)
        {

            sem_post(&mutex);
            sem_post(&mutex1);
            break;
        }  

        sem_post(&mutex);
        sleep(2);

    }

    consumerArray1[i] = '\0';
    pthread_exit(NULL);

}

void *Consumer2(void *ptr)
{

    int i = 0;
    sem_wait(&mutex1);
    bool loopCond = endOfFile;
    while(!loopCond)
    {

        if(endOfFile)
        {

            loopCond = charQueue.empty();
            std::cout<<loopCond<<std::endl;
            sem_post(&mutex1);
        }
        sem_wait(&mutex1);


        sem_wait(&mutex);


        if(!charQueue.empty())
        {

            consumerArray2[i] = charQueue.front();
            charQueue.pop();
            i++;
        }  
        if(charQueue.empty()&& endOfFile)
        {

            sem_post(&mutex);
            sem_post(&mutex1);
            break;
        }  



        sem_post(&mutex);
        sleep(4);

    }

    consumerArray2[i] = '\0';
    pthread_exit(NULL);

}

int main()
{
    pthread_t thread[3];
    sem_init(&mutex,0,1);
    sem_init(&mutex1,0,1);
    pthread_create(&thread[0],NULL,Producer,NULL);
    int rc = pthread_create(&thread[1],NULL,Consumer1,NULL);
    if(rc)
    {
        std::cout<<"Thread not created"<<std::endl;
    }
    pthread_create(&thread[2],NULL,Consumer2,NULL);
    pthread_join(thread[0],NULL);pthread_join(thread[1],NULL);pthread_join(thread[2],NULL);
    std::cout<<"First array: "<<consumerArray1<<std::endl;
    std::cout<<"Second array: "<<consumerArray2<<std::endl;
    sem_destroy(&mutex);
    sem_destroy(&mutex1);
    pthread_exit(NULL);
}
```

Comment: @DavidSchwartz please check this and tell what improvements I should make. really sorry for bothering you. this is my first pthread/semaphore code. so please understand.